# Using perl script i'm generating exel sheet, having sum(student_amount) with this i'm getting +ve and -ve amount i'm getting

Tags: excel, perl

The problem is for positive amount in excel it showing like 2.00 and for negative -2.000 i can't understand why it showing 3 digits for negative value and not for positive value ! can any one help here, Thanks in advance

I'm writing into excel like this in my code:

```
my $formatamt=$workbook->add_format();   
$formatamt->set_num_format('0.00');
```

Comment: Could you write code here to show how you writing to excel cells?

Comment: Which module are you using?

Comment: Below is the code that i used to generate excel                                    my $formatamt=$workbook->add_format();        
$formatamt->set_num_format('0.00'); 
$current_ws = $workbook->add_worksheet();    
#Amount is the second position  
$current_ws->set_column(2,2,10,$formatamt);             
#Below is the header for the Amount          
$current_ws->write_string(0,$cl++,"AMOUNT",$format);       

if (isfloat($_)){        
            $current_ws->write_number($rownum,$clcntr++,$_);}       
        else{       
            $current_ws->write_string($rownum,$clcntr++,$_);}

Comment: @Dr.Avalanche., I don't how to check which module it is, but when i type perl -v it displayed like below
   This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: @Siva you have `use` statements where you `use` modules. If you wrote the script you should know what modules you're using

Comment: Thanks guys i got the answer

Answer (score -2):

The result(Amount) that i'm getting from an sql output, so i have specified the format there itself. Thanks guys